# Multiple steps in approval process

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have multiple steps in approval process 
[image]

Updated from approval to next step (Still getting error)
[image]

My requirement is if the max value is greater than 5 the it need approval. Eg :- if my max value is 60. here I want it should get approve from all the steps 1,2,3,4. Step 1 when max > 5 , Step 2 when max > 25, Step 3 when max > 40 and Step 4 when max > 50. But here when I submit my record it is going to Step 1 (to the manage of the record owner) when  the manager approves it. It get approved and the approval process get stop. It is not moving to Step 2. Anyone here please guide me what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Look at the criteria for step 1, if it doesn't match the criteria, it is automatically approved.  You might want to change it to else next step, so it goes to the next step.

Comment: If it doesn't meet the criteria (i.e. <5) then it doesn't need to go to the next step, right? If is does meet the criteria, then after approval it should go to step 2, as expected. So the question is: why isn't that happening?

Comment: @guy yes my question is why this is not happening. what is I need to change to get it working.

Comment: Well.. I think first you should give Chris' idea a shot. You never know, there might be a bug or a documentation error. If that doesn't work, there might be an error in the numbers. E.g. mixup between percentages and numbers.. Also did you check that this process is active and not some prior one.

Comment: @ChrisDuncombe, I made the change but still the same issue it get approved at the first level. Please check the question I have updated with new image.